# parametrizing chart in google data lab

Tags: charts, google-visualization, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab, pygooglechart

I know how to parametrize a single bigquery using %%bq. But how do I then parametrize the %%chart using that bigquery?

When I tried adding a parameter following the guidance in this doc /notebooks/datalab/docs/tutorials/BigQuery/BigQuery%20Parameterization.ipynb (on my datalab instance) 
it did not work

Answer (score 2):

I was able to parametrize queries used in charts using 
`query_name = bq.Query(query_string)`, which is plain python.

bq is from `import google.datalab.bigquery as bq`.

`%%chart columns --data query_name --fields ...` uses the query in query_name.